# Variable length sequences for RNN, using functional keras API

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm, autoencoder

I'm currently using this implementation (1 input = 1 encoder and 2 output = 2 decoders in my autoencoder RNN-network):

```
input_tensor = Input(shape=(None, features))

enc = LSTM(timesteps, activation = 'tanh', return_sequences = True)(input_tensor)
enc = LSTM(timesteps, activation = 'tanh', return_sequences = False)(enc)
    
decode1 = RepeatVector(timesteps * 2)(enc)
decode1 = LSTM(200, activation = 'tanh', return_sequences = True)(decode1)
decode1 = LSTM(timesteps, activation = 'tanh', return_sequences = True)(decode1)
decode1 = TimeDistributed(Dense(8, activation="softmax"), name="dec1")(decode1)

decode2 = RepeatVector(timesteps)(enc)
decode2 = LSTM(int(timesteps), activation = 'tanh', return_sequences = True)(decode2)
decode2 = TimeDistributed(Dense(2, activation = "tanh"), name="dec2")(decode2)
    
new_model = Model(inputs=input_tensor, outputs = [decode1, decode2])
```

But this does'nt work. I know it's possible to have variable sequence lengths in the Sequential Model, but isn't it possible in the functional keras API? Because I really need 2 output decoders... Anyone who can help?

Comment: please clarify the problem. I recreated your model with no errors. Sequential API works with RNN - https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/rnn

Comment: @Andrey which datatypes do you provide as inputs? Because I get the error: "Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray)". I know it works with the Sequential model, but then it's not possible to have 2 parallel output-decoders (or is there?).

Comment: I only get this error because the sequences have a variable length...

Answer (score 0):

Your model works:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, LSTM, RepeatVector, TimeDistributed, Dense
from tensorflow.keras import Model
features = 10
timesteps = 10
input_tensor = Input(shape=(None, features))

enc = LSTM(timesteps, activation = 'tanh', return_sequences = True)(input_tensor)
enc = LSTM(timesteps, activation = 'tanh', return_sequences = False)(enc)
    
decode1 = RepeatVector(timesteps * 2)(enc)
decode1 = LSTM(200, activation = 'tanh', return_sequences = True)(decode1)
decode1 = LSTM(timesteps, activation = 'tanh', return_sequences = True)(decode1)
decode1 = TimeDistributed(Dense(8, activation="softmax"), name="dec1")(decode1)

decode2 = RepeatVector(timesteps)(enc)
decode2 = LSTM(int(timesteps), activation = 'tanh', return_sequences = True)(decode2)
decode2 = TimeDistributed(Dense(2, activation = "tanh"), name="dec2")(decode2)
    
new_model = Model(inputs=input_tensor, outputs = [decode1, decode2])

import numpy as np

#input = tf.random.uniform([100, 10, features], 0, 10, dtype=tf.int32)
input = np.random.uniform(0, 10, [100, 10, features])
output = new_model(input)
```